# Expressjs not handling the multipart data

Tags: node.js, express

**What i am doing** ::

- I am trying to post a image from client and which i want to print the name of the file in my console
- This image is of `multipart`

---

**what is not working**::

- my express is not handling the `multipart` data on the server

---

**app.js**

```
var http=require('http');
var crypto=require('crypto');

var app=express();


app.set('port',process.env.PORT||7002); 

app.use('/Details',express.static(__dirname+'/public/images'));

//.use(express.cookieParser());

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/Details/',function(req,res,next){



        var file_name=req.files.key.originalFilename;
        console.log(file_name);


});

app.get('/Details/',function(req,res){
        res.send("Image displayed");
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){
        console.log('Express server listening on port'+app.get('port'));

});
```

---

**Error in my console** ::

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at C:\ExpressPractice\imageUpload\app.js:21:32
    at callbacks (C:\ExpressPractice\imageUpload\node_modules\express\lib\router
\index.js:164:37)
    at param (C:\ExpressPractice\imageUpload\node_modules\express\lib\router\ind
ex.js:138:11)
    at pass (C:\ExpressPractice\imageUpload\node_modules\express\lib\router\inde
x.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (C:\ExpressPractice\imageUpload\node_modules\express\lib
\router\index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (C:\ExpressPractice\imageUpload\node_modules\express\lib\ro
uter\index.js:33:10)
    at next (C:\ExpressPractice\imageUpload\node_modules\express\node_modules\co
nnect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
    at multipart (C:\ExpressPractice\imageUpload\node_modules\express\node_modul
es\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:86:27)
    at C:\ExpressPractice\imageUpload\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\
lib\middleware\bodyParser.js:57:9
    at C:\ExpressPractice\imageUpload\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\
lib\middleware\urlencoded.js:76:7
```

---

**How can i debug this**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the attribute of the form with  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

The form should be

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem --- Expressjs code was correct but form, i had not set it as multipart/form-data ......... I resolved it, Thanks